# PHP How can i use my select to change the value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this problem, I need the **type** my `select`, to deside which tolerance to use.

Lets say, I have 2 (or more) options in my `select`, one called test1 and one called test2, each has an `type_id` and a `type_name`. and their table is called `type_tb`

And i have 2 (or more) tolerances which i want to be able to change via the `select`, they are in a table called `tol_tb`.

so when i select `test1` then the row in `tol_tb` where the `tol_id` is 1 is used and if i select `test2` then the row in `tol_tb` where the `tol_id` is 2 is used

How can i do so that when i `select` test1 then the values that i use inside the tol_tb is changed to the values connected to the test1?

to better explain it ill show you some code pieces, but before i do that i think you might need to see how my database is currently setup.

ive already said how the `type_tb` is set up with a `type_id` and a `type_name`,

the tolerance table `tol_tb` is a little bigger. It looks like this,
it has a `tol_id`, `tol_p_A_maal`,and a `tol_m_A_maal`. its longer than that but its basicly the same all the way, the `tol_p_A_maal` and the `tol_m_A_maal`. is values of the tolerance where the p stands for plus and the m stands for minus I think i makes more sense when you get further into the code.

This is my `select`

```
 <select class="form-control" name="type" id="exampleFormControlSelect4">
        <?php foreach ($products->getAllType() as $type) { ?>
        <option value="<?= @$type->type_id ?>" selected><?= @$type->type_name ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

And this is my input field for when i write a measure

```
<div class="form-group col-2">
    <label for="A_maal">A: Mål</label>
    <?=@$error['A_maal']?>
    <input type="text" name="A_maal" id="A_maal" class="form-control" value="<?= @$_POST['A_maal'] ?>">
</div>
```

and then i have this code piece that does so that i dont get a undefined index error if the input field is empty,

```
$A_maal = isset($_POST['A_maal']) ? $_POST['A_maal'] :$tol->tol_m_A_maal + $tol->tol_p_A_maal * 0.5;
```

everything until here works as it should. This is the part I haven't been able to get to work.

so the idea is that i want it use the selected type. to deside which tolerance is used. ive tried many things without any success. here is my latest attempt,

```
foreach ($products->getAllTol() as $tol) {
if ($tol->tol_m_A_maal > ($A_maal) || $tol->tol_p_A_maal < ($A_maal)){

    include './includes/modal.php';
    $notification->setTolaranceErrorNotification();
    }
}
```

Long story short. I need the type to be the selector of the tolerance.

Hope this edit better explain my problem.

**Better explained database setup**

I have 2 tables.

One called `type_tb`

and one called `tol_tb`

`type_tb` has the columns: `type_id`, `type_name`
there are 2 rows in this table atm.

`id:1`, `name:test1`

`id:2`, `name:test2`

and `tol_tb` has the columns: `tol_id`, `tol_m_A_maal`, `tol_p_A_maal`.

there are also 2 rows here.

ignore the weird names, just remember that the `m` and the `p` is the important part here.

`m` stands for minus - smallest number allowed

`p` stands for plus - largest number allowed

what i think could work would be to make a foreign key or something alike. but i dont know how i should connect it in my code.
and again any help is really appreciated

Comment: Besides I think your if clause doesn't do what you expect. I don't get your problem. Try to clearly state your actual problem. Not the problem with your solution to the actual problem. Also include the full minimal code to reproduce that problem.

Comment: ill try edit my question, thanks for the reply!

Comment: The best solution whould be to use AJAX: basically, each type you select a new value in your first select (type), you send a request through AJAX to fetch the corresponding tolerences linked to the type selected and update the options in the second select with the result from this AJAX request.

Comment: dont know if i explained it wrong, or understand what you are saying wrong, but what im trying to do is if the tolerance A: is 2-10 so that everything between 2 and 10 is allowed,and B: has a tolerance of 5-20 so everything between that is allowed, and everything outside that range gives and error (the include), so when i pick inside the select A: then when i write inside the input field a number between 2-10 then its allowed. and when i select option B: then everything between 5-20 is allowed.

Comment: My bad, i read you question too fast and didn't see the second field is an input.

Comment: Why don't use the HTML input "number" type which allow you to take advantage of two attributes : "min" and "max : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number

Comment: I need to be able to change them, without having to upload the code again :)

Comment: well the code does work to an extend, the thing is it takes the last added row from my database, and i want to be able to select the row with the correct tolerance

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify your db structure, i don't clearly understand how you set it?

Comment: should maybe add a foreign key to the tolerance from the type_tb. but still dont know how to link it correctly in the foreach.

Comment: will do. ill explain every table ive got

Comment: I've updated the question. look at the last part of the question.

Comment: I confirm, you need to add a column which will hold the type_id to create a relation between the to entities. With this, it should be easy to retrive any tolerance linked to a type. BUT if a tolerance can be linked to several type, then you should use a relation table instead.

Comment: so if i link the tolerance id, the tol_id to the type_id then, how would you do so that when you select the type_id:1 the one named test1, then it would actually use that tolerance linked to it.

Comment: The queston is: can you have : A - only one tolerance for one type / B - several tolereances for one type / C - serveral tolerances for several types ?

Comment: i need to have several tolerances for one type, so that tol_id 1is connected with the id of the type, and inside the row of tol_id 1 is a row with multiple tolerances. so there are more columns, i dont need to be able to add more columns just be able to make new tolerances when a new type is created

Comment: If you have several tolerances for one type, then rather than adding several columns to the type_tb table, you should just add one column (type_id) to the tol_tb table it's more efficient and allow you to select all tolerances linked to one type really easily.

Comment: yea that is a good idea but how do i use it? can you give an example of how you would use it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so first of all you need to set up the tables like this in your database:

**type_tb :**

- type_id
- List item

type_name

**tol_tb :**

- tol_id
- tol_m_A_maal
- tol_p_A_maal
- type_id

  *the type_id column will contain the id of the type the rolerance is linked to.*

Then where you post your form, you have 2 values : 
- type (the type id)
- A_maaal (the tolerance the user fill in your input)

use the "type" value (the type_id) to fetch all tolerances linked tot it :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tol_tb` 
WHERE type_id = :type_id
```

where you replace the `:type_id` by the value you get from your form (type selected).

This MySQL request should be in a new method : getAllTolByTypeId($type_id) (for example) with the proper fetch (object to respect your initial coding).

and perform your test as you already did :

```
foreach ($products->getAllTolByTypeId($type_id) as $tol) {
        if ($tol->tol_m_A_maal > ($A_maal) || $tol->tol_p_A_maal < ($A_maal)){

            include './includes/modal.php';
            $notification->setTolaranceErrorNotification();
        }
    }
}
```